# "open=" command of autorun.inf not working

Tags: windows, cx-freeze, drive, autorun

I wrote a backup script using Python and I used [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to convert it into `backup.exe`. I put this executable on my USB flash drive. If I run `C:\> E:\backup\backup.exe`, it works, my files are copied to the USB flash drive.

Then I put this `autorun.inf`:

```
[autorun]
open=backup\backup.exe
label=BackupUSB
```

When I plug the USB flash drive, the label is correctly set to `BackupUSB` but the files are not copied.
Why?

**EDIT:** I added a line `action=Run backup` in the `autorun.inf` but the option is not displayed in the menu...

Comment: Because autorun from USB was disabled like 10 years ago for security purposes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically launch app on USB (through autorun?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255006/automatically-launch-app-on-usb-through-autorun)

Comment: @CodeCaster I checked, it is enabled on my Windows 10.

Comment: Define "it" and "enabled". You cannot autorun directly from an USB drive since somewhere around Windows Vista, period. Some USB sticks can launch executables on insertion because they have a hidden CD drive that does support autorun. The "beauty" of USB at work.

Comment: @CodeCaster The checkbox [Control Panel > AutoPlay > Use AutoPlay for all media and devices] is checked. As I use a french version, I just understood that "autorun" is not "autoplay"... If autorun is not possible I just would like to display the option (using `action=` in `autorun.inf`?) in the menu when I plug the USB flash drive... But it doesn't work neither: the action is not displayed in the menu.

Comment: That is also not possible, thanks to [Conficker](http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/conficker.aspx) (see [screenshot](http://www.microsoft.com/global/security/publishingimages/pc-security/Autoplay.jpg)). I guess the answer to your question then simply is _"This is not possible"_, mind if I post that?

Comment: @CodeCaster Ok! thanks

Answer (score 4):

The commands "open" and "action" only works in Windows Vista and Windows XP only. After Windows 7, Microsoft removed this feature from USB stick due to security problems. So from Windows 7 to the latest version of Windows will not support "open" command and "action" command.

Comment: Then, what we should do to create auto-plays for our assistant disks?

Comment: any solution so far ?